# React map array and return only labels

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a component in React which needs to map through a simple array:

```
var data = [{ older: 2 }, { "Nov 23": 0 }, { "Nov 24": 0 }, { "Nov 25": 3 }];
```

I need to map this array so it creates a new array of only the labels
i.e.

`["older", "Nov 23", "Nov 24", "Nov 25"]`

How is this done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects and you want to get an array of strings.
You can use the `map` array method and the `keys` object method, like this:

`var labels = data.map(obj => Object.keys(obj)[0])`

you'll get:

`// ["older", "Nov 23", "Nov 24", "Nov 25"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) i.e.

```
var labels = data.map(x => Object.keys(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var data = [{ "older": 2 }, { "Nov 23": 0 }, { "Nov 24": 0 }, { "Nov 25": 3 }];

  var keys = [];
  var labels = data.map(
    (value) => {
      keys.push(Object.keys(value)[0]);
    }  
  );

  console.log(keys);
```

Comment: Hi @onurkaya, you're relatively new here so I'd like to recommend that you take a look at the guide [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It's always good to have a explanation about your solution, not just code.